# Android preference and AmbilWarnaDialog

Tags: android

I have preferences.xml with Checkbox, List, etc.. ..
I want to add an option to change the font color. I want to use the ColorPicker - AmbilWarnaDialog (I know how to use it)

What field I need to create that when you click open ColorPicker.